# Is There Any High-Level Library for convolution supporting open-GL?

Tags: python-3.x, opengl

I want to build a cross-platform application that contain some convolution layers. It seems open-GL support convolution operation but they're hard to understand how to use. Is there any high-level library to use convolution on open-GL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems open-GL support convolution operation

In OpenGL-1.2 there were a few built-in convolution operations introduced, but these never got any particular development from vendors and the whole codepath is either unoptimized, runs on the CPU or buggy.

Don't bother using it.

If you want GPU accelerated convolution, your best bet is to implement it as a shader. Depending on the size of the convolution kernel it might be desireable to perform the convolution in Fourier space, i.e. Fourier transform both signal/image and kernel, multiply element wise then transform back.